# HTML CSS Table border-radius property not applying

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table in this format:

```css
.main-table {
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  height: 30vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-radius: 3vw;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  width: 87vw;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
}

th {
  height: 2vw;
  background: #deb724;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td {
  height: 3vw;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td:hover {
  background: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Hello </th>
        <th> World </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> Wow look </td>
        <td> What is this </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

There is a border-radius property on the table, however it's not applying. I have been looking up and all I can find is set border-collapse as separate, but that didn't do it either. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to table.

```css
.main-table {
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  height: 30vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-radius: 3vw;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  width: 87vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
}

th {
  height: 2vw;
  background: #deb724;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td {
  height: 3vw;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td:hover {
  background: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Hello </th>
        <th> World </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> Wow look </td>
        <td> What is this </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Actually it is applied, but overflows it outside. We can see that by adding border to table in the below snippet. That's why we should add `overflow: hidden`

```css
.main-table {
  margin-top: 1vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  height: 30vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-radius: 3vw;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  width: 87vw;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
}

th {
  height: 2vw;
  background: #deb724;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td {
  height: 3vw;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td:hover {
  background: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Hello </th>
        <th> World </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> Wow look </td>
        <td> What is this </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```